# Plant Shape 1 spell

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

I was doing something with the [plant shape spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plant-shape-i) and noticed that plant shape 1 medium has a +2 enhancement bonus to con, but when you start using plant shape 2 and 3, it changes to a size bonus. Is this a typo in the spell or is there some logical reason why it would be an enhancement bonus instead of size like all the others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be, but it’s impossible to know for sure if this was intentional or just an error.

Enhancement bonuses are “weaker” than other types of bonus, because they are so common (and typed bonuses don’t stack). Someone with a *belt of mighty constitution* sees no benefit from *plant shape I*’s Constitution bonus, but does from that of *plant shape II* and *III*. That could be intentional, a way in which the higher-level spells are more powerful. And *plant shape I* does apply a size bonus to Strength in the same line it applies an enhancement bonus to Constitution, so you could argue that it’s not like they “forgot” to use size bonuses or something.

On the other hand, it is weird, and other polymorph effects don’t seem to do that—they just give size bonuses to Constitution. Moreover, it’s very easy to imagine someone saying “oh those are supposed to be size bonuses,” and fixing the Strength bonus—the first one on that line—and then moving on to further lines without scanning to the end, and so missing the enhancement bonus to Constitution.

So really it could go either way. It’s certainly playable/sensible as written, and there **might** be reasons to do that intentionally, but it’s still weird and unusual, and looks like it might very plausibly be a mistake. There’s not really any way to know for sure. As a 5th-level spell, though, I definitely rule that *plant shape I* gives a size bonus to Constitution—even if they intended the enhancement thing as a drawback of the lower-level spell, I don’t think it’s deserved.

Comment: I'm personally gonna lean on it likely being a typo/editing oversight. Ruling as a size bonus is a solid move.

Comment: Both me and my dm agree that it being a enhancement didnt make sense, and you had most of my thoughts and more.